# Two keys in a map literal shouldn't be equal

Tags: flutter

The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.

Comment: Please include the code for the error statement

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to judge without seeing your code, but that error message means that your function doesn't return a Widget in all cases. It's probably similar to

```
Widget getWidget() {
  if (condition) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that this function doesn't return anything when the condition is not true, but it is required to do so. It can be solved by doing this for example

```
Widget getWidget() {
  if (condition) {
    return Container();
  }
  return Container();
}
```